# What's the methodology for adequate tetrahedralisation?

Tags: materials, finite-element-method, simulation, elastic-modulus

I'm running a linear elastic solver generating the tetrahedron's using tetGen. It's not clear to me though how one defines what's an acceptable tetra density that provides sufficient accuracy.

You can see that in the picture below the maximum displacement drastically decreases alongside an increase in tetra count.

This is a much as my machine is able to process but I assume it would converge around 90k tetrahedron. Is it at that point that we can consider the results to be accurate?

Can someone provide a guideline that can be translated programmatically?

[image]

Comment: I always understood that the increased mesh density was useful where the most effects that had to be analysed were... So, for a fluid going round a 90 deg bend - then around the corners etc

Comment: That'd make sense, in which case I assume you'd have a mesh refinement in areas of high stress. Perhaps every x number of iterations?

Comment: Some software allows for increasing the iterations over particular areas ie weighting the computational power... more timesteps or finer timesteps etc